# How do I delete number of files from folder in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

i have a list of albums and photos in albums. Now i want when i delete a particular album then its photos also to be delete.The name for images of a particular album is like " if album's id is 1 so its images name should be 1_1,1_2,.. . So i have got the image name upto "1_" at the time of deletion of album. now i am confused how to delete the images which have prefix "1_". my code is

```
`For Each Alb_Id In Col_Alb_Ids
Dim imagefolder As String = ""
imagefolder = Server.MapPath("~/DesktopModules/Album/Images_Uploaded/")
Dim ss As String = Alb_Id & "_"
imagefolder.Contains(ss)
Dim aa As String = imagefolder + ss
If File.Exists(imagefolder.Contains(aa)) Then
  File.Delete(aa)
End If`
```

Comment: What happens when you debug through the code?  Do you see in `aa` the path you expect?  Does the debugger enter the IF branch?  Do you get an Exception of some kind?

Comment: yes its but the prob is i want to delete 1_1 so when it comes to if condition it shows this image is not found in the folder.. so . this is the prob..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Directory.GetFiles` passing in a wildcard for the search:

C# code

```
String[] albumFiles = Directory.GetFiles(imageFolder, ss + "*.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imagefolder.Contains(ss)

Dim aa As String = imagefolder + ss
If File.Exists(imagefolder.Contains(aa)) Then
      File.Delete(aa)
End If
```